# Остановить AJAX запрос

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Как правильно остановить данный скрипт выполнения на определенном месте, кликая на кнопку.

Использую кнопку для запуска id="button" а для остановки не работает кнопка id="button_stop"

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  var total = 100;

 $(function() {

  $('#button').click(function() {

   $("#status_script").ajaxError(function(event, request, settings){
      $(this).html('<font color="red">ошибка отправки</font>');
    $('#button').attr("disabled", false);
    });
    
      $('#error_script').html('');
   $('#status_script').html('<b>идет обработка, ждите...</b>');
   $('#button').attr("disabled", "disabled");
   $('#button').val("Продолжить граббинг");
   
   senden( $('#grabbing_ok').val() );
   return false;
  });
  

 });

function senden( startfrom ){

xhr = $.post("/script.php?user_hash={$login_hash}", { startfrom: startfrom, area: 'script_go' },

  function(data){ 

   if (data) {

    if (data.status == "ok") {

     $('#nomer').html(data.script_count);
     $('#id').html(data.id);
     $('#grabbing_ok').val(data.script_count);

     var proc = Math.round( (100 * data.script_count) / total );

     if ( proc > 100 ) proc = 100;

     $('.progress-bar').css( "width", proc + '%' );


            if (data.script_count >= total) 
            {
                 $('#status_script').html('<font color="green">успешно завершен</font>');
            }
            else 
            { 
                 setTimeout("senden(" + data.script_count + ")", 1000 );
            }


    }

   }
  }, "json").fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $('#status_script').html('<font color="red">ошибка отправки</font>');
      $('#button').attr("disabled", false);
      $('#error_script').html(jqxhr.responseText);
     });
  
 return false; 
    
}

$('#button_stop').click(function() {

    $('#button').attr("disabled", false);
    xhr.abort();
  
  return false;

  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Заменил

setTimeout("senden(" + data.script_count + ")", 1000 );

на

senden(data.grabber_count);

В php прописал sleep(1); // Задержка 1 секунда

После этого заработал xhr.abort();

Comment: это не `xhr.abort()` заработал,а ты кликать в кнопку начал успевать